# Custom ad banner in iAd Framework for iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, iad

I just wonder can we use our own banner to implement in an app when using iAd framework??

Does someone have any guide or tutorial or document on this. Thank you very much for your help.

Regards, 
Tony

Answer (score 2):

You could use [adwhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/) with iAd as a backend, and use adwhirl to show your own ad ("house ad") a certain percentage of the time.

We're doing it ourselves in one of our apps, works as expected.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. Do you have any guide or tutorial on how to set up adwhirl and iAd together? I only can find the guide for iAd